# python: too many parameters provided

Tags: python, class, parameter-passing

could anyone please explain what's wrong with it ? am I doing something wrong ?

```
>>> class qw: 
...     def f2x(par1, par2, par3): 
...             print par1, par2, par3 
...
>>> obj = qw()
>>> obj.f2x("123", 13, "wert") Traceback (most recent call last):  
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: f2x() takes exactly 3 arguments (4 given)
>>>
```

if I will define just a function it's all working fine

```
>>> def f2x(par1, par2, par3):
...     print par1, par2, par3
... 
>>> f2x("1", 2, "too many")
1 2 too many
>>>
```

Comment: Did you have `self` as the first argument to your function declaration before or after the answers came along to this question?  Are you still having problems?

Comment: could you please edit the question back to its original form so that the responses make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess its because of every method of a python class object implicitly has a first paramter which points to the object itself.

try

```
def f2x(self, par1, par2, par3):
```

you still call it with your 3 custom parameters

```
>>> class qw:
...     def f2x(self, p1, p2, p3):
...             print p1,p2,p3
... 
>>> o = qw()
>>> o.f2x(1,2,3)
1 2 3
```

Comment: I think you mean 'explicitly'?

Answer (score 4):

You forgot that all member functions get another argument implicitly, which in Python is called `self` by convention.

Try:

```
class qw:
  def f2x(self, par1, par2, par3):
    print par1, par2, par3
```

But still call it as before:

```
obj = qw()
obj.f2x("123", 13, "wert")
```

In `f2x`, `self` is the object on which the member was called. This is a very fundamental concept of Python you should really learn about.

Answer (score 4):

You need the `self` parameter in your class' instance method definition:

```
class qw:
    def f2x(self, par1, par2, par3):
        print par1, par2, par3
```

I'd suggest going through a beginner Python book/tutorial. The [standard tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/) is good choice, especially if you already have some experience in another language.

Then you call it like so:

```
g = qw()
g.f2x('1', '2', '3')
```

Comment: @m1k3y02: what python are you using? it runs fine in my machine after adding the self parameter.

Comment: 2.6.5, after re entering python command line all started to work as it is supposed to, thank you for your help